# How to do a sensitivity analysis for causal mediation analysis after multiple imputation (and when both outcome and mediator are binary)?

Tags: r, imputation, mediator, causality

I am looking to perform some sensitivity analyses using the mediation package (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mediation/mediation.pdf) with already imputed data. There doesn't seem to be a function for this, as the function `medsens()` does not work on `ameliadate()` objects. Is the only way to go about this to use the `medsens()` function on each imputed dataset separately?

I tried to use `medsens()` on the individual imputed datasets, but this wasn't possible, as both my outcome and mediator are binary probit. I understand that `medsens()` can only work if at least either the outcome of mediator follow a linear model. Is there some other form of sensitivity analysis that is recommended when both outcome and mediator are binary? Thank you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.